# How to uninstall SQL server 2005 and fixpack on a server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL server 2005 with fixpack 2 installed on one server on C drive.

I need to uninstall it and reinstall in the E drive, can someone please help.

Comment: uninstalling try to repair it first (just to make shure that uninstallation process will be clean)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot uninstall *service packs* you need to uninstall all of SQL Server, then re-install it.

To uninstall you can do so from Control Panel -->Add Remove Programs
Then select the sql server components & select uninstall

Answer (score 0):

Why not just edit the service instance so that it runs from the C drive but stores all data and databases on the E drive?   You could do that without re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all entries for SQL in Add/Remove Programs, including the SQL native client and the XML piece.  SQL 2005 sets a "shared tools" path on the install of the first component and that cannot be moved without removing everything.  Also, a good old windows reboot afterward can't hurt either.